# vertical center alignment to the paragraph in the container.

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

Friends, here is a very simple problem I am facing. I am having a container called 'testDiv', and inside the container one paragraph to test. The problem is when I am targetting to the paragraph ( .testDiv p ) and assigning margin-top: 75px;, it is affecting to the container also. so, here is what i want. I want to move-down only the paragraph not the container. Is there any poosibility without using absolute position to the paragraph.

here is what i tried so far - http://jsbin.com/adudih/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. Work with `padding-top` and not `margin-top`:
   http://jsbin.com/etazem/2/edit
2. Use `line-height` on the paragraph tag and set it to the **same height** as your container: (With this method you will have problems with **text-wrapping** if the text overflows the container width):
   http://jsbin.com/etazem/1/edit

**Padding vs Margin:**
http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-between-margins-padding-css/

Comment: Ya. It is working just fine. But can you tell me one thing - why it is not working, when we are assigning margin property to the paragraph. we are targetting the paragraph itself, then also it is affecting to the container. any reason.

Comment: Look at what happens if `float: left;` is added: http://jsbin.com/etazem/5/edit This is due to something called Collapsing margins read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins and more about Block formatting: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`. So it should be

```
.testDiv p {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 75px;
  color: white;
}
```

**Update:** 
The reason why it affect the container is because you've assign the styling like this `.testDiv p`. It will refer to `.testDiv` first, then only `p`.Another way you can just style the paragraph by assigning a class name for it and do the margin.

```
<div class='testDiv'>
    <p class="p-style">Some text to play around.</p>
</div>

.p-style{
    margin-top: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Ted2F/1/

For `p` css, use `float & margin-top` instead of `line-height`

Play around the p margin-top and see.

```
.testDiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.testDiv p {
    float:left;
    background:green;
    margin-top: 130px;
    color: white;
}
```